# How can I make Outlook Add-In to not load from scratch on item change

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Im currently developing Outlook Add-In, which is supposed to be a CRM. It loads 3rd party Web App in the task pane, where user has to log in. On desktop Outlook, I can make task pane pinnable and refresh it on item change. On the OWA, it looks like I can't pin my task pane, but I want at least to force Add-In, to not reload itself each time user changes e-mail. It loads from scratch every time with new session/cookies and user needs to relog again. Any ideas if it is possible? Or how can I work around this?

Comment: The pinnable task pane feature is already available on OWA. Could you tell us the endpoint you're using (URL)? Are you using the same add-in on Desktop and OWA? Could you give us steps to reproduce the issue on our end?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I don't think I can give you URL, since it's our companies Exchange Server. I'm logged in with my companies Exchange account in Outlook, and when I deploy Add-In for my account, I can use pin in Outlook client, but I don't have it in the OWA. I asked admins to make me an additional account that has mailbox on office.com, and when I deploy Add-In for that account I can use pin in Web Outlook accesed from office.com

Comment: Can you check your network trace (either using an app like Fiddler, or using the browser) if a request goes to userBootSettings.aspx or userBootSettings.ashx when you reload the page? If yes, can you check if the response contains "addin-persistentTaskPane" for the "features" key?